# android – How to leave empty space in GridLayout

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I have `GridLayout` (from support library) where are two rows of buttons. All buttons have width set to 2 and height 1. The first row should be shifted one position to the right. When I do this, the `GridLayout` works like the first row is not shifted.

Second row:

```
GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
params.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(1, 1, 1);
params.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(x, 2, 1);
```

First row:

```
GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
params.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(0, 1, 1);
params.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(x + 1, 2, 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to insert dummy views to all cells on top and on the left (start).

```
for (int x = 0; x < gridLayout.getColumnCount(); x++) {
    GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
    params.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(0, 1, 1);
    params.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(x, 1, 1);
    params.setGravity(Gravity.FILL);
    params.width = 0;
    gridLayout.addView(new Space(this), params);
}
for (int y = 0; y < gridLayout.getRowCount(); y++) {
    GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
    params.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(y, 1, 1);
    params.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(0, 1, 1);
    params.setGravity(Gravity.FILL);
    params.width = 0;
    gridLayout.addView(new Space(this), params);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a nicer (IMO) solution that I came up with;

```
<GridLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:useDefaultMargins="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Space android:layout_columnWeight="1" />
    <Space android:layout_columnWeight="1" />
    <Space android:layout_columnWeight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:text="01"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack"
        android:padding="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="02"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack"
        android:padding="15dp" />


    <!-- REPEAT ITEM HOWEVER MANY TIMES -->


</GridLayout>
```

Here's how it renders with 4, 3, 2 and 1 item in the grid with default margins added to the GridLayout;

[image: Shows how GridLayout renders with 4, 3, 2 or 1 items]